# Swift: Labels not showing up

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, uilabel

I am trying to make labels defined by an array in Swift but when I try to do this and I run the app, they just don't show up. My code for the view controller is right here:import UIKit

```
class SmallPainViewController: UIViewController {

    var tips = ["Play your favorite videogame", "Watch a movie", "Watch YouTube"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        for (i, tip) in tips.enumerate() {
            let tipLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(i*50+150), 0, 30, 30))
            tipLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i*50+150), 0)
            tipLabel.text = tip
            tipLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            self.view.addSubview(tipLabel)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: `tipLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i*50+150), 0)`, why? You didn't have enough by setting its frame? Also, did you mean `tipLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i*50+150), 15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var tips = ["Play your favorite videogame", "Watch a movie", "Watch YouTube"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    for (i, tip) in tips.enumerated() {
        let tipLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (i*50+150), y: 150, width: 30, height: 30))//CGRect(CGFloat(i*50+150), 0, 30, 30)
        tipLabel.center = CGPoint(x: (i*50+150), y: 150) //CGPoint(CGFloat(i*50+150), 0)
        tipLabel.text = tip
        tipLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.view.addSubview(tipLabel)
    }
}
```

I think you are using swift 2.0

Comment: I am actually using 2.1

Comment: I had to slightly modify it to go to my Swift version